# How to start React JS application in background mode on linux?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, I want to start my react application in background mode or in detach mode. In Ruby On Rails `-d` option is available to start application in background mode. How should I do this in ReactJS application.

I tried running  `npm run build`, it generated the optimised production build. Please suggest.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look on [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) this should be exactly what you want.

To install pm2 :

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

To start an application simply just run :

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

You can check logs via:

```
pm2 logs
```

To stop current pm2 instances

1) list the pm2 processes, get the id, lets say the id is 0

```
pm2 ps
```

2) then stop the id

```
pm2 stop 0
```

Comment: `pm2 start app.js` started app.js file, but on which port my app has started ? How should I visit started application ?.I am looking to start application in background mode.

Comment: I the same as you would start the app normally. So on your programmed defined port or you can pass it `pm2 start app.js 3000`

Comment: not working I started it using `start app.js 3000`. but still not able to access on browser. please advice

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

> Build the project, get the build folder and put it inside the public directory of a running server instance (apache, nginx etc).

You can build the project by `npm run build` if you have your build script defined in your `package.json` and then serve the build folder with `serve`
first install serve

```
npm install serve -g
```

then run serve

```
serve -s build -l port_number
```

if you want this to run in background and maintain the log, redirect the standard out and error out to a file, execute following

```
serve -s build -l port_number &> filename.log &
```

if you just want to run serve it in background

```
serve -s build -l port_number &
```

You can use `nohup` as well

```
nohup bash -c 'npm start' &
```

`&` for background processing